# Onclick radio button show different pricing based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a parent class in which I have two radio buttons. I want to show div based on attributes of parent class.Means If I select box A the it should show the value based on it.  The code is partially working and I am bit confused as what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 choose-type" data-type="1" data-doc='0'>
        <div class="hovereffect">
            <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="info">ORDER NOW</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4 class="overlay_wrap">ABC</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 choose-type" data-type="2">
        <div class="hovereffect">
            <div class="overlay">
                <a class="info">ORDER NOW</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4 class="overlay_wrap">XYZ</h4>
                            </div>
<div class="radio-toolbars time-slot">
    <div class="radio_oneimg" data-delivery='two' data-doc='0'>
        <input type="radio" data-attr="1" id="radio2" name="answer[43]" value='' checked="checked" required/>
        <label for="radio2"><p>QWRTY<span class="doc_print"></span> vbnx<span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio_oneimg" data-delivery='three' data-doc='1'>
        <input type="radio" data-attr="2" id="radio3" name="answer[43]" value='' required/>
        <label for="radio3"><p>apply</p><span><span class="doc_print"></span> vbnx<span></label> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="doc_price"><span><i></i></span></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.radio_oneimg').bind('click', function(e){
    if ($(this).attr('data-doc') == '0') {
        $('#radio2').on('click', function(){
            $('.doc_price span i').html(999);
        })
        $('#radio3').on('click', function(){
            $('.doc_price span i').html(2999);
        })
    }
    if ($(this).attr('data-doc') == '1') {
        $('#radio2').on('click', function(){
            $('.doc_price span i').html(799);
        })
        $('#radio3').on('click', function(){
            $('.doc_price span i').html(2499);
        })
    }
})
```

If data-doc is 0 I want to print the price 999 or 2999. If data-doc is 1 I want to print 799 0r 2499 based on click of radio button. As it is showing only one price from the above field and 2end price from the 2end script. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong.

Comment: $('.radio_oneimg') is a div not the radio button

Comment: any solution will not work cause whatever your html is differ then your tried javascript code. data-doc="0" have only radio2 child not radio3 and same in data-doc="0" not available radio2

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this. in your current code, binds click event on radio button when click on div so it is not correct way it seems click event after first click on div. I have written code in normalize way what you need and as per my understanding.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#radio2',function(){
     var val = $(this).parent().data('doc') == '0' ? 999: 2999;
     $('.doc_price span i').html(val);
      
});
$(document).on('click', '#radio3', function(){
     var val = $(this).parent().data('doc') == '0' ? 799: 2499;
     $('.doc_price span i').html(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbars time-slot">
    <div class="radio_oneimg" data-delivery='two' data-doc='0'>
        <input type="radio" data-attr="1" id="radio2" name="answer[43]" value='' checked="checked" required/>
        <label for="radio2"><p>QWRTY<span class="doc_print"></span> vbnx<span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio_oneimg" data-delivery='three' data-doc='1'>
        <input type="radio" data-attr="2" id="radio3" name="answer[43]" value='' required/>
        <label for="radio3"><p>apply</p><span><span class="doc_print"></span> vbnx<span></label> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="doc_price"><span><i>0</i></span></div>
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. And is there really need of an event delegation?!

Comment: And check your code, there were issues in it. It is currently not working.

Comment: @eisbehr, I have added explanation in code, and code is working correctly... so please remove down vote

Comment: Thanks,  Now, Preety Shigh will decides :)

Comment: Haresh Only one price is showing 999 0r 2999 the second price is not showing

Comment: @PreetySingh, ahh I missed to pass `val` in html() method... now I think its fine... thanks

Comment: @PreetySingh, have you got solution?

Comment: HareshVidja your answer was useful thank you so much. Yeah I did found a solution I have used your code partially var val = $(this).parent().data('doc') == '0' ? 999: 2999; these line and done it in another way and it's working fine. I guess I was not able to ask the question properly. Infact thanks to everyone. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @PreetySingh, Thanks for your feedback, I have tried give best answer as possible as according to your question description. if you like then mark as correct.. and can you provide your linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need?

```
$('.radio_oneimg').bind('click', function(e){
if ($(this).attr('data-doc') == '0') {
    $('#radio2').on('click', function(){
        $('.doc_price span i').html("999");
    })
    $('#radio3').on('click', function(){
        $('.doc_price span i').html("2999");
    })
}
if ($(this).attr('data-doc') == '1') {
    $('#radio2').on('click', function(){
        $('.doc_price').html("799");
    })
    $('#radio3').on('click', function(){
        $('.doc_price').html("2499");
    })
}
})
```

Comment: Please compare mine with yours carefully.
As eisbehr said that, there is no span i inside .doc_price, therefore I change the javascript to work with your html.

Comment: I am sorry there is span i in doc price I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no `span i` inside `.doc_price`
2. you have to remove the `click` around, just bind it to the `radio` elements directly
3. you should use `change` instead of `click`
4. you can combine the event listeners and use just two instead of four
5. you should use `data` instead of `attr` to get the value of `data-doc`

```js
$('#radio2').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().data('doc') == '0') {
        $('.doc_price').html(999);
    }
    else if ($(this).parent().data('doc') == '1') {
        $('.doc_price').html(799);
    }
});
  
$('#radio3').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().data('doc') == '0') {
        $('.doc_price').html(2999);
    }
    else if ($(this).parent().data('doc') == '1') {
        $('.doc_price').html(2499);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbars time-slot">
    <div class="radio_oneimg" data-delivery='two' data-doc='0'>
        <input type="radio" data-attr="1" id="radio2" name="answer[43]" value='' checked="checked" required/>
        <label for="radio2"><p>QWRTY<span class="doc_print"></span> vbnx<span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio_oneimg" data-delivery='three' data-doc='1'>
        <input type="radio" data-attr="2" id="radio3" name="answer[43]" value='' required/>
        <label for="radio3"><p>apply</p><span><span class="doc_print"></span> vbnx<span></label> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="doc_price"></div>
```

Comment: And why? What are you missing? @PreetySingh

Answer (score 0):

Just update this line.

```
<div class="doc_price"><span><i></i></span></div>
```

And it will start showing price.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function () {
        var radioId = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataDoc = $(this.parentElement).attr("data-doc");
        $('.doc_price').html('');
        if (dataDoc == "0") {
            if (radioId == 'radio2') {
                $('.doc_price span i').html(999);
            }
            if (radioId == 'radio3') {
                $('.doc_price span i').html(2999);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (radioId == 'radio2') {
                $('.doc_price span i').html(799);
            }
            if (radioId == 'radio3') {
                $('.doc_price span i').html(2499);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: because your html seems wrong : data-doc='0' has only radio2 child not radio3, your requirement confusing

Comment: If parent div hase data-doc='0' and radio button comes under this then it should work right?

Comment: YES, required radio2 and radio3 should be under div